# QSyntaxHighlighter rehighlight() ignores changes triggered from another thread

Tags: qt, qml, syntax-highlighting

I have a spellchecking thread which fires `spellcheck()` signals from time to time which are connected to my highlighter's `rehighlight()` method. The latter sets the whole block to have red foreground.

This used to work in Qt 5.6.2 and ceased to work in newer versions. I hopelessly waited for it to get fixed in Qt 5.9.5, but it still does not work (neither in Windows 10, nor in OS X).

Small example which reproduces the problem could be obtained from here https://bitbucket.org/ribtoks/qt-highlighting-issue (in order to repro, type something in the input. `rehighlight()` will be triggered each 7 seconds from background thread)

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickTextDocument>
#include <QSyntaxHighlighter>
#include <QThread>
#include <QString>

class SpellCheckWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SpellCheckWorker(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent), m_Counter(0), m_IsOK(false)
    { }

public:
    bool isOK() { return m_IsOK; }

signals:
    void spellcheck();

public slots:
    void process() {
        qInfo() << "Worker Thread is" << QThread::currentThreadId();
        while (1) {
            m_Counter++;
            m_IsOK = m_Counter % 7 == 0;
            QThread::sleep(1);
            emit spellcheck();
        }
    }

private:
    int m_Counter;
    volatile bool m_IsOK;
};

class SpellCheckErrorsHighlighter : public QSyntaxHighlighter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SpellCheckErrorsHighlighter(SpellCheckWorker *worker, QTextDocument *document):
        QSyntaxHighlighter(document),
        m_Worker(worker)
    { }
    virtual ~SpellCheckErrorsHighlighter() {}

protected:
    virtual void highlightBlock(const QString &text) override {
        if (!m_Worker->isOK()) {
            qDebug() << "Worker is not OK" << text;
            return;
        }

        qInfo() << "Reapplied formatting for" << text;
        qInfo() << "Highlight thread is" << QThread::currentThreadId();

        this->setFormat(0, text.length(), QColor(0xff, 0, 0));
    }

private:
    SpellCheckWorker *m_Worker;
};

class MainModel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
public:
    explicit MainModel(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent), m_Worker(nullptr)
    { }

public:
    QString name() const { return m_name; }
    void startChecking() {
        qInfo() << "Main thread is" << QThread::currentThreadId();
        m_Worker = new SpellCheckWorker();
        QThread *thread = new QThread();
        m_Worker->moveToThread(thread);

        QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::started, m_Worker, &SpellCheckWorker::process);
        thread->start();
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void initNameHighlighting(QQuickTextDocument *document) {
        SpellCheckErrorsHighlighter *highlighter = new SpellCheckErrorsHighlighter(m_Worker, document->textDocument());
        QObject::connect(m_Worker, &SpellCheckWorker::spellcheck,
                         highlighter, &SpellCheckErrorsHighlighter::rehighlight);
    }

signals:
    void nameChanged();

public slots:
    void setName(QString name)
    {
        if (m_name == name)
            return;

        m_name = name;
        emit nameChanged();
    }

private:
    SpellCheckWorker *m_Worker;
    QString m_name;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainModel mainModel;
    mainModel.startChecking();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQmlContext *rootContext = engine.rootContext();
    rootContext->setContextProperty("mainModel", &mainModel);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

and `main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow  {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    StackView {
        id: mainStackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true

        initialItem: Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent

            Rectangle {
                id: titleRect
                height: 30
                width: 300
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: "#ffffff"
                border.color: "#000000"
                border.width: titleTextInput.activeFocus ? 1 : 0
                clip: true
                focus: false

                Flickable {
                    id: titleFlick
                    contentWidth: titleTextInput.paintedWidth
                    contentHeight: titleTextInput.paintedHeight
                    height: parent.height
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5
                    anchors.rightMargin: 5
                    clip: true
                    flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick
                    interactive: false
                    focus: false

                    function ensureVisible(r) {
                        if (contentX >= r.x)
                            contentX = r.x;
                        else if (contentX+width <= r.x+r.width)
                            contentX = r.x+r.width-width;
                    }

                    TextEdit {
                        id: titleTextInput
                        width: paintedWidth > titleFlick.width ? paintedWidth : titleFlick.width
                        height: titleFlick.height
                        text: mainModel.name
                        focus: true
                        onTextChanged: mainModel.name = text

                        Component.onCompleted: mainModel.initNameHighlighting(titleTextInput.textDocument)
                        onCursorRectangleChanged: titleFlick.ensureVisible(cursorRectangle)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Is there any way to get it working with workarounds?* I need to keep spellchecking logic in the background thread so it's not possible to move it to main thread.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because the code is not provided here? From a quick look at the repo, there isn't that much code there, so you should be able to easily get it down to a main.cpp and main.qml.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for the tip. Added main code here.

Comment: It should be runnable though - the code you've added can't be put into a main.cpp and main.qml and run. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/mitchcurtis/4792dfaa46b8a40b9ffcbc0e33b20283 for an example.

Comment: @Mitch I tried, but it's impossible to have several objects with `Q_OBJECT` macro in main.cpp. I'm getting many linking errors. https://bitbucket.org/ribtoks/qt-highlighting-issue

Comment: That's cause you're missing the `#include "main.moc"` in the example I linked to. :p

Comment: Thanks @Mitch indeed obviously I forgot.

Comment: this code appears to be working... what exactly is supposed to happen? Your code makes it so every 7th letter typed causes the text to turn red, but deleting the text doesnt do anything, and other typed letters make the text black.. is this the expected behavior or is something else supposed to happen?  Can you clarify your question by being more specific... see [ask]

Comment: @mike510a Hey, if the question is unclear for you, please don't give any irrelevant random answer to it.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be referring to two different root causes with the following two statements:

> There's NO problem in delivering slot call to Highlighter.

and

> m_Worker->isOK() check is there for a reason to execute highlighting only once per 7 seconds. The bug in Qt can only be demonstrated with this.

If I just focus on the second statement, it looks like the problem is that you are not able to hit the statement `if (!m_Worker->isOK())` right?

That may well be a problem due to your code or a Qt issue on a specific platform. 
Can you change the code to avoid the condition i.e. emit the `spellcheck` signal only when 7 seconds have passed to avoid making this check from another thread?

Answer (score -3):

Ok, so after messing with your code,  The issue is that you are not calling this line inside of the hilightBlock directive in `main.cpp` near line 55 in order to keep the format from before.

Add this in to fix it (I think)  The question was still fairly unclear...

```
if (!m_Worker->isOK()) {
    qDebug() << "Worker is not OK" << text;
    this->setFormat(0, text.length(), this->format(0));
    return;
}
```

The other part of the issue is that you don't have any rules defined for the syntax highlighter... so it will always be red once it turns red.

Comment: Why do I need to inherit from `QThread`? Qt "best practice" is to implement it the way it is implemented (`moveToThread()` and `process()`). What benefits will inheriting from the `QThread` provide to me?

Comment: Also `rehighlight()` slot is being called from the main thread.

Comment: There's NO problem in delivering slot call to Highlighter. It is being called. I don't need to inherit from `QThread` to achieve that. Actually it is wrong to do that. The problem raised in this question is that after `setFormat()` is being called (from the main thread), the format is not applied to the `TextEdit`. If you think that inheritance from `QThread` will help here, you're very much welcome to try it out and report back - check the code in header.

Comment: `m_Worker->isOK()` check is there for a reason to execute highlighting only once per 7 seconds. The bug in Qt can only be demonstrated with this. If you just remove it it will work as well but this is how race condition (possibly or some other problem) could be shown.

Comment: Also it will not be red as soon as you type something in. So it doesn't stay red forever.

Comment: the code you posted currently works. it turns red every 7th letter then once you type it turns to default color again... whats your question?

Comment: The code does not work or works unreliably using Qt framework of versions 5.6.3 and above. The question is how to overcome this.